# SSH and PING timeout on new AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Unable to launch an EC2 instance that I can ssh into. I am using an ubuntu AMI and try logging in using "ssh -i .pem ubuntu@

The strangest thing is that right when I launch the instance, I am able to ping it and ssh into it for a max 2 minutes(just when the status checks are being run). But once the status checks are complete, the instance is unreachable.

I feel like I've tried everything that people say to try online. I've also posted this question on the AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=712790#712790

Comment: what is the output with `-v` option to ssh?

Comment: OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8

debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/connorocallaghan/.ssh/config

debug1: /Users/connorocallaghan/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-26-14-23.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [52.26.14.23] port 22.

debug1: connect to address 52.26.14.23 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-26-14-23.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: Sorry I can't get it to format any better than that, it comes up with a port 22 timeout.  But my security groups are allowing for all traffic.

Comment: Are you sure the machine is running? Is the security group open for access from your host?

Comment: The instance state says it is running in the aws console.  The security group is the default with an inbound rule allowing all traffic on all ports from source 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Try a different AMI.  If it still does it then the problem is local to you, not AWS.

Comment: I've tried a linux AMI and the same problem happens.  What could the local problem be?

Comment: that would depend on where you work, what software is installed on your local machine - a lot of unknowns